# Modify a parent theme's PHP file, and save in child theme

Tags: child-theme

I'm working with a paid theme, and we're using a child theme to display a slightly different design.

The parent theme has a file called /includes/forms/register-form.php

I'd like to customise this file, and save it in my child theme.

How do I tell Wordpress to use my child theme's version of this file, instead of my parent theme's version?

Comment: How is the file loaded in the parent theme? Based on the answer to that question, your answer is either below, or "you can't".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy register-form.php from your parent theme and paste it under yourchildtheme/includes/forms/register-form.php , from there start changes what you want and wordpress will use that file.

Comment: Are you sure?  I have tried this in the past, and it has not worked for non-template files.

Comment: @Steve yes, you can try to try `<?php echo "hello"; ?>` in very start of new copy template and see if that gets printed.

Comment: Whether or not this works depends on how the parent theme is loading the file. This is not guaranteed to work. It really depends a lot on the theme.

Comment: That's what I though s_ha_dum.  I did a search in folder for text using Notepad++, and the only mention of register-form.php in the theme folder was in themefolder\jobroller.pot, which is a language file.

Comment: It turns out @Nofel is correct!

Comment: @Steve :) enjoy